# Join query with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This performs proper sql query, but returns me only columns from one table

```
async def get_user_library(current_user = Depends(get_current_user)):
    async with get_session() as session:
        stmt = select(UserLibrary, Songs).join(Songs, UserLibrary.song_id == Songs.id).filter(UserLibrary.user_uuid == current_user)

        result = await session.execute(stmt)
        library_items = result.scalars().all()
    return library_items
```

Here is my models

```
class Songs(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'songs'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    artist = Column(String)
    title = Column(String)
    length = Column(Integer)


class UserLibrary(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'library'
    library_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    song_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('songs.id'))
    play_count = Column(Integer)
    added_at = Column(DateTime)
    user_uuid = Column(String, ForeignKey('users.uuid'))
```

Comment: I can't think of a reason why making it async would change what it returns. Do you get the expected result if you do it synchronously?

Comment: I had this problem before with synchronous way and couldn't solve it, so I just switched to raw sql queries, this time I decided to try sqlalchemy one more time and got same problem

Comment: So it's just a general sqlalchemy problem, sync/async is irrelevant.

Comment: I think I'm just doing something wrong

Comment: Obviously, but your title suggests that the question is about async.

Comment: I just provided more details, my first time asking on this site actually

Comment: See the examples of join [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy_orm_working_with_joins.htm). I don't think you should put both tables in the `select()` function and also use `.join()` -- one or the other.

Comment: It selects only columns from one table if I remove one table from select, statement that I wrote performs SELECT library.*, songs.* 
FROM library JOIN songs ON library.song_id = songs.id 
WHERE library.user_uuid = $1::VARCHAR
And this is exactly what I want

Comment: Look at the examples on the page I linked to -- they return columns from both tables.

Comment: Idk this just doesn't work I tried everything

Comment: Then I guess you'll have to wait for someone who knows SQLAlchemy better than me to come along and help.

Comment: This returns me "[(<controllers.db.models.UserLibrary object at 0x7fe975cb5b40>, <controllers.db.models.Songs object at 0x7fe975cb5ae0>)]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `.scalars()` in this case. The rows in your `library_items` will contain attributes for both `UserLibrary` and `Songs` under their respective names [1](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/select.html#selecting-multiple-orm-entities-simultaneously). So you'll have to pass those rows into your objects.

Alternatively, you could use a `relationship` to load the related objects for you automatically. [2](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/basic_relationships.html#basic-relationship-patterns)